# Generate parameters in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want an update method in the controller to get parameters in a specific format. The current format by which I am getting the parameters is

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"temp", "performance_areas"=>{"0"=>{"performance_area"=>"New item"}, "1"=>{"performance_area"=>"Delete Item"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

This is being generated as a name in my text field with 0 and 1 indicating the areas index. I want some additional parameters in this in the following format:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"temp", "performance_areas"=>{"0"=>{id: 1, description: "This is a test","performance_area"=>"New item"}, "1"=>{id: 2, description: "This is a test2","performance_area"=>"Delete Item"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Any pointers how to get the parameters in the way I want. I do have performance_areas that has the id and description in it. Do let me know if any further clarification is required.

EDIT: Form code (just pasting the critical section of the long code)

```
<%= form_tag({:performance => :update}, :method => :put) do %>
<% @performance_areas.each_with_index do |performance_area, i| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :performance_area, performance_area, :name => "performance_areas[#{i}][performance_area]" %>
<%= submit_tag %>
```

Comment: Paste the code of your form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this, I am assuming that both `id` and `description` are in `performance_area` object

```
<%= form_tag({:performance => :update}, :method => :put) do %>
  <% @performance_areas.each_with_index do |performance_area, i| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :id, performance_area.id, :name => "performance_areas[#{i}][id]" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :description, performance_area.description, :name => "performance_areas[#{i}][description]" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :performance_area, performance_area, :name => "performance_areas[#{i}][performance_area]" %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That does it, could please explain how that works? would be really helpful !!

Comment: `"performance_areas[#{i}][performance_area]"` is generating the params that way. Your parameters look like `"performance_areas"=>{"0"=>{"performance_area"=>"New item"}`. Just compare both, you will get to know that it depends on the `name` attribute of your `hidden_field_tag`

Comment: So it smartly aggregates all common keys under one value?

Comment: It is a common HTML form thing, the name of your hidden field is `"performance_areas[#{i}][performance_area]"`, where `i` is the index, so every time the loop iterates the index value behaves as a new key in the params, rails manipulates it in the form of hash. So, it looks like `performance_areas => { "0" => { "performance_area" => "New Item" } }`, here "0" is the index value you mentioned in the `name` attribute and `"New Item"` is the value of `performance_area`