# Access params hashed with integer - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is directly in reference to this question I had asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987305/generate-parameters-in-ruby-on-rails)
My parameters are generated as,

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"temp", "performance_areas"=>{"0"=>{id: 1, description: "This is a test","performance_area"=>"New item"}, "1"=>{id: 2, description: "This is a test2","performance_area"=>"Delete Item"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

I am trying to access the [:id] in the controller where I iterate using:

```
params[:performance_areas].each_with_index do |performance_area_parameters,i|
puts performance_area_parameters[i][:id]
end
```

Gives me errors. I tried a host of other methods trying to convert i to string and some others as well, could not succeed. Is it possible to access id the way I am doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way

```
params[:performance_areas].values.each_with_index do |value,i|
  puts value["id"]
  puts value["description"]
  puts value["performance_area"]
end
```

Comment: Nailed it ! Will accept after the duration is complete

Answer (score 0):

also another solustion could be

```
params[:performance_areas].each |value| do
  value.each|i,p| do
    puts i + p
  end
end
```